# jQuery AJAX - where jQuery gets and uses the returned data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 2.3.5

With Protype, I had a function that was called when an Employee ID was entered into a form.  The function would make an AJAX call and then fill the Employee's details into the form (number, location, title, manager, etc.).  I'm trying to learn up on how to do the same thing with jQuery.

EMPLOYEE FIELD ON FORM

```
<%= f.text_field :employee_id, :maxlength => 7, :onkeyup => 'employee_lookup(event)' %>
```

OLD PROTOTYPE CONTROLLER OUTPUT:

```
 employee = CorporateDirectory.find_by_employee_id(params[:employee_id])
render :text => employee.first_name+", "+employee.last_name+","+employee.desk_phone+", (etc.)
```

FUNCTION INSERTING RETURNED DATA INTO FORM

```
var employeeData = (x.responseText.split(','));
$('employee_first_name).value = employeeData [0];
$('emplyee_last_name').value = employeeData [1];
$('employee_desk_phone').value = employeeData [2];
```

I used :onkeyup and then in the function I had it return false if it didn't have the proper number of characters (7) or if the format was wrong (not 2 alpha + 5 numbers).

If there's a good exmaple or tutorial of how to do the same thing with jQuery and Rails, I'd love to see it. Or, a heads-up on exactly what exactly I should be reading up on would be welcome.   I've been using jQuery AJAX to replace html with partials and load UI Modals with views or partials, but I haven't done anything yet where I had to request data with jQuery and then have jQuery use the data itslef.  In this case I need to have a Rails model object sent to jQuery where jQuery can read the array of data returned and properly fill out the matching form fields.   Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need a custom method in your controller like:

```
def search
  @employee = CorporateDirectory.find_by_employee_id(params[:employee_id])
end
```

Then use [this](http://employee%20=%20CorporateDirectory.find_by_employee_id%28params%5B%3aemployee_id%5D%29) to post to the search method.

In your controller, you want the search method to respond to :js which, by default, will render the search.js template.  You can use search.js.erb and use the @employee object in the view.  Your jQuery script will be like so:

```
$('#employee_first_name').val('<%= @employee.first_name %>');
```